# Angular Jasmine Test Modal and Resolve Result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test functionality which is basically doing,

- Open confirmation modal
- Return result of modal (button value which are OK or Cancel)
- If condition checks result
- Calling another function

My controller function is;

```
openPopup() {
  confirmationModal.open().then((result) => {
    if(result === 'OK') {
      someService.doSomething()
          .then(() => {        
            showSuccess();
          }); 
        }
      }).finally(() => {
        confirmationModal.close();
      });
}
```

And my test is;

```
describe('confirmation modal', () => {
beforeEach(() => {

    inject(($controller, _$q_) => {
      var q = _$q_;

      someService = {
        doSomething: jasmine.createSpy()
      };

      var modalResult = {
        then: function(callback) {
          callback("OK");
        }
      };

      confirmationModal = {
        open: jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(q.when({ result: modalResult })),
        close: jasmine.createSpy()
      };

      Ctrl = $controller('MainController', { 
        $scope: scope, confirmationModal: confirmationModal, someService: someService
      });
    });
  });

  it('should pass OK value', () => {
    Ctrl.openPopup();

    scope.$digest();

    expect(someService.doSomething).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

When I run this through Karma - PhantomJS, I'm getting **Expected spy unknown to have been called.** which is I assume I can't go through If condition with modal result. Basically need to test conditional modal result If I can.
When I test and expect open or close functions of confirmationModal, test passes but If I expect function after confirmationModal has been called, test fails.

I'm struggling with this maybe basic thing and I'm really sorry already If I miss some rules or my bad english.

Thanks already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for stubbed service to be used by the app it should be injected, and currently it is not injected. In controller it can be injected with `$controller` local dependencies:

```
  Ctrl = $controller('MainController', { 
    $scope: scope, confirmationModal, someService
  });
```

`result` is supposed to be a string, not an object and especially not an object that simulates promises like `modalResult` does. It is

```
  confirmationModal = {
    open: jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(q.when('OK')),
    close: jasmine.createSpy()
  };
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, actually I cut it off when I was trying to copy/paste so controller actual has dependency with service. And thanks for the help actually I figured it out I was sending wrong string, actual condition checking some string else :)

Comment: The condition is quite straightforward. Since it expects a string, it should work as expected with `.and.returnValue(q.when('OK'))`.